# How to remove background in sketch?

Tags: background-removal, sketch-app

I've got an image I'm trying to remove the background from and I'm not really sure how that would be done with Sketch. Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: What is Sketch, has something to do with Skencil?

Comment: @Aradnix https://www.sketch.com/ Sketch is a vector graphics editor for macOS.

Answer (score 14):

Sketch 3 does have some bitmap editing options, but they are very limited.

Here's more about [Bitmap editing](http://bohemiancoding.com/sketch/support/documentation/06-images/1-bitmap-editing.html) in Sketch.

> To start editing an image, select it on the canvas and double-click. You will see the inspector update with a few special tools.

[image]

You might wanna try your luck with `Magic wand` and then the `Vectorize` option below it. Although you'd probably be better off redrawing it with the `Vector tool`.

---

I would recommend you use another application to edit bitmap images. One relatively cheap, option would be [Pixelmator](http://www.pixelmator.com/) especially considering how much Sketch 3 costs. Then again you could do it in [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) just the same.

Comment: Thank you, for the longest time I thought I had to do this separately in Photoshop!

Answer (score 5):

You can use the the Instant Alpha tool (magic wand) in the macOSX Preview to remove the background.

http://www.chriswrites.com/how-to-use-previews-instant-alpha-magic-wand-tool-in-os-x/